# How to read multiple text files from hdfs symlink

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, symlink, mapr

I am trying to read multiple parts files of hdfs symlink  from spark. I am able to use wildcard(*) to read multiple files from path if path is physical 
e.g. 
`sparkContext.textFile(/some/path/file_123321_00/part-r-000*)`

But I have created symlink to this folder on hdfs called 'fullset'. and when I use
/some/path/**fullset**/part-r-000*  it fails to detect any paths. 
I tried `hadoop fs -ls` on both path. First one works but one one with symlink doesn't work as expected. 
 We are using MapR distribution which allows us to create such symlinks but I am not sure now what's the best way to read from it from Spark. Reason we create symlinks is to point it to latest data set.
Any suggestion are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Nirav, 
Can you post your workaround here ?

Answer (score 0):

MapR specific workaround. Notice use of MapRFileStatus instead of hadoop FileStatus.

`FileSystem fs =  FileSystem.get(conf); 
 MapRFileStatus fst = (MapRFileStatus)fs.getFileStatus(path);
 Path target = fst.getSymlink();`